# In "Windows Subsystem for Linux" how can I change from being a root user to a just plain user?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

in linux how can I change from being a root user to a just plain user?

When I boot into bash on Windows 10 I now see:

"root@STANSTOY:/home/wojowhisky#"

how do I get it to boot to:

"wojowhiskey@STANSTOY:~$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To switch to a user in Linux:

```
su - wojowhiskey
```

To make your user a sudoer:

```
sudo visudo
```

And then add or edit the following line:

```
wojowhiskey ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Yes, that works but how do I get to boot into bash as user wojowhiskey not root?  What file must I amend?

Comment: I did manage to make it work by placing "su wojowhiskey" in the $HOME/.bashrc file.  Now however I can not access the root file.

Comment: Yes because the root files are owned by the root not wojowhiskey. Whenever you have to access those files, either you prefix your command with `sudo` or type `sudo su -` to switch to root user

Comment: wojowhiskey@STANSTOY:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for wojowhiskey:
wojowhiskey is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
wojowhiskey@STANSTOY:~$

Comment: I get this when I first login to bash:

Comment: You must add the user to sudoers. I edited my answer for that

Answer (score 2):

Few days ago I had to set default user to root in order to change user password.
To set default user do:

```
<distro> config --default-user <user>
```

**In my case**

To set **root** as default:

```
ubuntu1804 config --default-user root
```

To set **anand** as default:

```
ubuntu1804 config --default-user anand
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Windows command prompt: (don't type it in `bash.exe`)

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser wojowhiskey
```

**lxrun** is pretty powerful, check it out:

```
C:\> lxrun /?
Performs administrative operations on the LX subsystem

Usage:
    /install - Installs the subsystem
        Optional arguments:
            /y - Do not prompt user to accept
    /uninstall - Uninstalls the subsystem
        Optional arguments:
            /full - Perform a full uninstall
            /y - Do not prompt user to accept
    /setdefaultuser - Configures the subsystem user that bash will be launched as. If the user does not exist it will be created.
        Optional arguments:
            username - Supply the username
            /y - If username is supplied, do not prompt to create a password
    /update - Updates the subsystem's package index
```

Comment: For new Windows 10 release Fall Creators Update and later, lxrun is deprecated. Use distro_name.exe instead, i.e., ubuntu.exe http://aka.ms/wslusers